# How can I improve my Server and Client "SMTP" code?

Tags: java, email, smtp

I've been assigned a tast to implement an SMTP client-server protocol providing limited functionality and the Solution for this is to execute a typical execution simiilar to this transcription:

```
S: 220 [ip]
C: HELLO [email]
S: 250 Hello [email], pleased to meet you
C: MAIL FROM: <email1@email.com>
S: 250 ok
C: RCPT TO: <email2@email2.com>
S: 250 ok
C: DATA
S: 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
C: Hello,
C: Test Email
C: .
S: 250 ok Message accepted for delivery
C: QUIT
S: 221 [ip] closing connection
```

Essentially, it's not supposed to send any emails or anything but more simulate the process of sending an email through an SMTP.

I've taken the easy route of using Cases and Switches so when it reads the data, it prints out exactly what i want, but i want to know if there's a way i can get the Client's input and read it in the server to produce an ouptut similar to the trasncript i've written. And also how can i code it any better?

Here's the Server code:

```
 package TCPSocket;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class TCPServer{
    private ServerSocket server;

    /**
     * The TCPServer constructor initiate the socket
     * @param ipAddress
     * @param port
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public TCPServer(String ipAddress, int port) throws Exception {
        if (ipAddress != null && !ipAddress.isEmpty())
            this.server = new ServerSocket(port, 1, InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress));
        else
            this.server = new ServerSocket(0, 1, InetAddress.getLocalHost());
    }

    /**
     * The listen method listen to incoming client's datagrams and requests
     * @throws Exception
     */



    private void listen() throws Exception {
        // listen to incoming client's requests via the ServerSocket
        //add your code here
        String data = null;
        Socket client = this.server.accept();
        String clientAddress = client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
        System.out.println("\r\nNew client connection from " + clientAddress);

        // print received datagrams from client
        //add your code here
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        while ( (data = in.readLine()) != null ) {
            //System.out.println("\r\nMessage from " + clientAddress + ": " + data);

            switch (data){
                case("HELLO 192.168.56.1"):
                    System.out.println("\r\n250 Hello " + clientAddress + ", pleased to meet you");
                    break;
                case("MAIL FROM: <test1@gmail.com>"):
                    System.out.println("\r\n250 ok");
                    break;
                case("RCPT TO: <test@email.com>"):
                    System.out.println("\r\n250 ok");
                    break;
                case("DATA"):
                    System.out.println("\r\n354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>");
                    break;
                case("."):
                    System.out.println("\r\nok Message accepted for delivery");
                    break;
                case("QUIT"):
                    System.out.println("\r\n221 " + clientAddress + " closing connection");
                    in.close();
                    break;
            }

            client.sendUrgentData(1);
        }
    }

    public InetAddress getSocketAddress() {
        return this.server.getInetAddress();
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return this.server.getLocalPort();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // set the server address (IP) and port number
        //add your code here
        String serverIP = "192.168.56.1"; // local IP address
        int port = 7077;

        if (args.length > 0) {
            serverIP = args[0];
            port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        }
        // call the constructor and pass the IP and port
        //add your code here
        TCPServer server = new TCPServer(serverIP, port);
        System.out.println("\r\nRunning Server: " +
                "Host=" + server.getSocketAddress().getHostAddress() +
                " Port=" + server.getPort());
        System.out.println("220 " + serverIP);
        server.listen();
    }

}
```

And here's the Client code:

```
package TCPSocket;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TCPClient{
    private Socket tcpSocket;
    private InetAddress serverAddress;
    private int serverPort;
    private Scanner scanner;


    /**
     * @param serverAddress
     * @param serverPort
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private TCPClient(InetAddress serverAddress, int serverPort) throws Exception {
        this.serverAddress = serverAddress;
        this.serverPort = serverPort;

        //Initiate the connection with the server using Socket.
        //For this, creates a stream socket and connects it to the specified port number at the specified IP address.
        //add your code here
        this.tcpSocket = new Socket(this.serverAddress, this.serverPort);
        this.scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    /**
     * The start method connect to the server and datagrams
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void start() throws IOException {
        String input;

        //create a new PrintWriter from an existing OutputStream (i.e., tcpSocket).
        //This convenience constructor creates the necessary intermediateOutputStreamWriter, which will convert characters into bytes using the default character encoding
        //You may add your code in a loop so that client can keep send datagrams to server
        //add your code here

        while (true) {
            input = scanner.nextLine();
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(this.tcpSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            //output.println("hello " + serverAddress);
            output.println(input);
            output.flush();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // set the server address (IP) and port number
        //add your code here
        InetAddress serverIP = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.56.1"); // local IP address
        int port = 7077;

        if (args.length > 0) {
            serverIP = InetAddress.getByName(args[0]);
            port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        }

        // call the constructor and pass the IP and port
        //add your code here
        TCPClient client = new TCPClient(serverIP, port);
        System.out.println("\r\n Connected to Server: " + client.tcpSocket.getInetAddress());
        client.start();
    }
}
```

Hopefully what i've written made sense and i appreciate any feedback and help provided

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Perhaps https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place for this kind of questions.

Comment: I'll post the same question on that website and see if i will get an answer there as well. Thank you @ETO

Comment: You're welcome! If you have anything you are struggling to solve, then feel free to post that here. The community will be eager to help in that case.

Comment: Isn't that just like one of your questions from yesterday? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66549923/how-do-i-host-my-own-smtp-server-using-java  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66534689/how-do-i-code-my-own-smtp-server-using-java

Comment: Yes @Robert but i re read the brief to discover that what i was asking help for was wrong. However i'm going to keep my original post up incase someone who has the same problem for a different reason stumbles upon it and may find it useful